# How can I capture context in a user-defined literal?

Tags: c++, c++11

I would love it if I could use a lambda as a user-defined literal, because then I could do something like:

```
struct Context
{
    // Maintains important context information
};

struct Foo
{
    Foo(Context& context, int value); // Foo needs a context to operate on
};

struct Factory
{
    Context& context;
    Factory(Context& context) : context(context) {}

    Foo operator() (int value) const
    {
        return Foo(context, value);
    }
}

int main()
{
    Context context;
    Factory factory(context);

    // I'd like to do something like this, but obviously it doesn't work
    using
    Foo operator"" _f = [&factory](int value) { return factory(value); };

    Foo x = 123_f;

    // But since that doesn't work, I have to do this:
    Foo x = factory(123);
}
```

Essentially, I have some objects that depend on a specific context (a garbage collector). In order to create these objects, I have to either pass in the context to the object's constructor, or I have to create a factory (which internally stores the context).

I have a lot of literals I'm working with (I'm creating lexing/parsing grammars). It's important for me to keep these complex grammars as readable as possible, and I personally find `123_f` more readable than `factory(123)` (or even `f(123)`, if I renamed `factory` to `f`).

I would love to use user-defined literals, but as far as I know I can't capture some kind of "working context" for the user-defined literals to work in. My understanding of user-defined literals is that they're defined in a global scope and thus can only access global objects, which is something I'd like to avoid (I have different grammars throughout the project).

Is there a way to create a user-defined literal that works with some local context?

Comment: Looks like an abuse to me.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yes and no. Yes, I'm abusing a lot of things in C++ (kind of like how [Boost.Spirit](http://boost-spirit.com/home/) abuses a lot of things in C++). But no, I'm not abusing things recklessly (though I wonder if methodical abuse is something I should consider "better" than reckless abuse).

Comment: I guess this is just a syntax problem, so what about alternatives such as `123_x(f)`? Otherwise, I think you'd have to use thread-local variables to emulate some kind of stack/scoping.